# Prove set of Nash equilibria is closed?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Is this even possible with just the formal definition of a Nash equilibrium, that is, without any additional conditions, such as the utility function is continuous?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can't prove this. Consider this counterexample.

(Edit:) **Take the mixed extension of**

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
1/2,1/2 & 0,0 & 0,0 & 0,0 & \cdots\\
\hline
0,0 & 3/4,3/4& 0,0 & 0,0 &\cdots\\
\hline
0,0 & 0,0& 7/8,7/8&0,0&\cdots\\
\hline
0,0 & 0,0 & 0,0&15/16,15/16&\cdots\\
\hline
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\
\end{array}
$$

Only in(cluding) the limit there is a NE yielding $(1,1)$, but this isn't a possible outcome.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible, however, if I assume more conditions, such as:

- The set $S_i$ of strategies for each player i is convex and compact.
- $u_i$ is continuous.

And the likes?

Comment: Sorry, edited :)

Comment: @BenjaminLu Taking the mixed extension of my counterexample, will give you counterexamples to 1) convex or 2) continuous. I'm thinking about 3) convex and compact...

Comment: I meant if I assume such conditions, will I be able to prove the set of NE to be closed?

Comment: I would think that _with_ 3) convex and compact, you might prove that, since the Cartesian product of the best-response functions will be compact. But I'm a little rusty. If you can't work it out, post _another_ question.

Comment: @BenjaminLu And of course there are plenty of trivial conditions where the set of NE is closed. Starting with all games with just one NE.

Comment: I asked another question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319908/nash-equilibria-and-best-response-functions

Comment: @Gugg You are showing that the set of NE *payoffs* is not closed, but the set of NE of your game is closed in a natural topology. When topologizing the space of pure strategies by any Hausdorff topology, the diagonal will be closed and the diagonal is exactly the set of pure strategy equilibria.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks. Should I have included in my counterexample "take the mixed extension of this game" explicitly? Will that be fine? Otherwise I'll have to figure out what a Hausdorff topology is. :)

Comment: @Gugg I'm not sure it is obvious what closed in the mixed extension means in this context. Well, I think there is anatural formulation, but not one the OP would be interested in. I think the question is ultimately meaningless without more information.

Comment: @Gugg Actually, the mixed extension makes life easier. Under any sensible formalization, expected payoffs are a continuous function.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks. I did have that in mind anyway, but thought I could do without. I'll change it.

Comment: Actually, are you sure that the set Nash equilibria of this game _isn't_ closed in the space of all possible mixed strategies? It's not really obvious to me.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm pretty sure. I'm trusting an intuition that goes like this. The mixed extension as a whole is (also literally) bounded by the lower-right edge (at $\infty^+$), which is outside of it, and which contains $(1,1)$. But I'm not a mathematician and not fluent in the concepts involved. Otherwise ask Greinecker.

Comment: Sure, but as you note, you can't actually play a strategy giving you a $(1,1)$ payoff, so that limit is not part of the strategy space. Perhaps more relevantly, for every finite, non-empty set of pure strategies your game has a unique Nash equilibrium with that set as its (mutual) support, and so you can take the sequence of Nash equilibria corresponding to the strategy sets $A_i=\{1,\dotsc,i\}$. I believe this sequence of strategies should converge in $\mathbb{R^N}$ under the product topology; but it converges to $(0,0,0,\dots)$, which is not a valid mixed strategy.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Your part 1): That's the whole point. Your part 2): Makes sense, _except for that_ the question is about the _set_ of NE, not about a distribution with a measure. (Aaah, I don't know, ask somebody else please.)

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, Gugg, Ilmari: You might want to click on the other question posted before continuing a discussion.

Comment: ...and read the comment below it, that is...

Comment: @gnometorule I doubt that *this* question is relevant to some take-home exam.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: I don't know - the other one is linked as a follow-up. I just thought you should be aware of it, so you can judge for yourself.